# Merging two DataFrames on DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas, merge, datetimeindex

I haven't had problems with such DataFrame operations until now.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to get a DataFrame, containing daily data for a few years period and hourly data for the last 5 days. My code (fully running):

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

ticker = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
fine = ticker.history(period='5d', interval='60m')
fine.index = fine.index.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None)
print(fine)
coarse_end_date = fine.index[0].date()
coarse = ticker.history(start='2019-01-01', end=coarse_end_date, interval='1d')
print(coarse)
yfdata = pd.merge(coarse, fine, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(yfdata)
```

Naturally, I'm trying to merge on both indexes (removing tz data from *fine* index first). What I get in result is an empty DataFrame:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open_x, High_x, Low_x, Close_x, Volume_x, Dividends_x, Stock Splits_x, Open_y, High_y, Low_y, Close_y, Volume_y, Dividends_y, Stock Splits_y]
Index: []
```

As you can see, merge operation splits similar DataFrame columns into _x and _y columns, and then, of course, there are no common values, hence the empty DataFrame.

I've tried assigning time to *coarse* dates, resetting indexes and merging on date column, renaming indexes, and other desperate stuff, but nothing worked.

Maybe someone has an idea of what's happening, I would highly appreciate your help

Comment: The index of `fine` is like `2021-03-30 19:30:00` and the index of `coarse` is like `2018-12-31`. They are not the same structure, thus their comparison will be always false.

Comment: Both are `DatetimeIndex`, it's only that time is hidden in case of `coarse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried some more desperate stuff, and apparently, I needed to specify columns I want to merge. Also, *outer* join method is required here.

`yfdata = pd.merge(coarse, fine, how='outer', on=coarse.columns.to_list(), left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: after update to pandas version 1.2.3 this solution no longer works. I actually needed to use *concat* method:  `yfdata = pd.concat([coarse, fine])`